# Unreal lose tracking of VR headset after launching an external VR exe application

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, oculus, virtual-reality

I created a VR experience in Unreal Engine, and inside the VR world, there is a button which can open an external exe, which is also a VR experence. It's like a VR menu room (Unreal application) and a mini VR game (not created by Unreal and is an external exe). When you play the mini game, Unreal VR menu is still open at the back.

I tried different ways to open external exe, such as:

```
FPlatformProcess::CreateProc

FMonitoredProcess

FInteractiveProcess
```

They can all successfully launch external exe, but the problem is, when the external exe is done playing and closed, the Unreal VR menu application will lose vision tracking of Oculus. This problem only happens if the external exe is a VR application. I tried to launch a regular exe, such as browser, and there is no lose tracking problem when I "alt tab" to jump back to Unreal VR application.

This is what I got from output log:

> LogHMD: Vision Tracking Acquired
>
> LogHMD: Lost Vision Tracking

Is this a bug of Unreal? Is there any way which can let Oculus retracked by Unreal after running an external VR exe?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oculus drivers should only handle one process at a time, so whenever that new application is starting, Unreal should give up its connection to the service because someone else is requesting the HMD to render those VR frames now. As a dedicated output, both applications issuing frames at the same time can't be a good thing.

Regarding your context, I suggest you try invoking the `"Stereo On"` Console Command to re-enable your HMD, though you might want to also try the Oculus specific `"HMD Enable"` command before hand.

*Personal concern: Keeping that menu in the background must be consuming resources as well and, in VR, that's an optimization issue you might have to address eventually.*

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful! I have "Stereo On" invoked when unreal application starts, and after the external exe is closed I will try to invoke again, to see if Unreal can re-link to Oculus. Any thoughts about optimization? I notice that the performance of external exe turns very bad when unreal menu is open full screen in the background. But it's not that bad when menu is windowed and not full screen, so I assume full screen menu will be consuming lots of resources? Any idea about how to do the optimization?

Comment: A quick thing to check is to manage the menu as a level, or as an entirely different application. With the first option, make the menu a Sublevel and unload it when you start the next application so you can release resources. The other option is... to exit your menu app and open it again when finished.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I try to invoke after the process complete,
and this is the code: 
void UExeFunction::OnProcessCompleted(int32 exitCode)
{
    GetWorld()->Exec(GetWorld(), TEXT("Stereo On"));
    auto riftHMD = GEngine->HMDDevice.Get();
    riftHMD->EnableHMD(true);
}
It still cannot go back to the original unreal application.

Comment: I am just thinking about your sublevel idea and I feel that maybe it can solve both the performance and connecting issue. If I reopen the menu sublevel, theoretically it should be connected.

Comment: so I tried your first option, make the menu a sublevel and unload it when I start the external exe. When the external exe is stop running, I turn on the stereo, enable the hmd device and load the menu sublevel back. However, it still doesn't work. When it goes back to Unreal menu application, the Unreal app is just got stuck at the place right before it launches the external exe, even though the blueprint is showing hmd is enable and Oculus is connected. It seems like Uneal app is working and Oculus is connected with Unreal, but the app is just broken.